# Stiefel-Whitney numbers for disjoint union of a Manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

I am reading the book by Milnor & Stasheff on Characteristics Classes, In the 4th Chapter There's is this beautiful result by Thom" If all of the Stiefel-Whitney numbers
of M are zero, then M can be realized as the boundary of some
smooth, compact manifold."

Just after which as an example It is written that "A disjoint union of two copies of a manifold M has all Stiefel-Whitney no. zero."

Why is that true? It can easily be seen by applying the converse of above as the disjoint union can be regarded as the boundary of M x [0,1].
Is there a way to directly prove it?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Stiefel-Whitney numbers are additive with respect to disjoint union and take values $\bmod 2$.

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan thank you for your comment but neither I am aware of this fact nor is the text which I am following, has proved it  Can you suggest something else?

Comment: What I was thinking is that a typical monomial in the Cohomology of the disjoint union will be the ordered pair of monomials of the individual cohomologies, Maybe same thing follows for the fundamental homology class?

Comment: It's an exercise; the argument in j.q.'s answer generalizes just fine to proving this, they don't use anywhere the assumption that the two copies of $M$ are the same manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear from the proof of additivity of cohomology under disjoint union that $H^*(M \sqcup M) = H^*(M) \oplus H^*(M)$ as rings.

It is also clear from the definition of the Stiefel-Whitney classes (for instance, naturality) that $w_i(M \sqcup M) = (w_i(M), w_i(M))$ above.

For a partition $p$ of $n = \dim M$ (a sequence of integers $1 \leq i_1 \leq \cdots \leq i_j \leq n$ with $i_1 + \cdots + i_j = n$) there is an associated product $$w_p(M) = w_{i_1}(M) \cdots w_{i_j}(M) \in H^n(M).$$

In your case, the first two sentences give you that $w_p(M \sqcup M) = (w_p(M), w_p(M)) \in H^n(M \sqcup M) = H^n(M) \oplus H^n(M)$.

Now the Stiefel-Whitney numbers of $M$ are obtained by pairing with the fundamental class; I write $s_p(M) = \langle w_p(M), [M]\rangle$ for this integer mod 2.

Then we have $$s_p(M \sqcup M) = \langle w_p(M \sqcup M), [M \sqcup M]\rangle = \langle (w_p(M), w_p(M)), ([M], [M])\rangle = \langle w_p(M), [M]\rangle + \langle w_p(M), [M]\rangle = 2s_p(M) = 0.$$

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how I was trying, Can you explain your third equality? @j.q

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Yes: the point is that not only do $H_*(M \sqcup M)$ and $H^*(M \sqcup M)$ split as direct sums, so does the action of cohomology on homology; that is, $H^*(M) \oplus H^*(M)$ acts on $H_*(M) \oplus H_*(M)$ by $(\psi, \phi) \cdot (x, y) = \psi(x) + \psi(y)$.

Comment: Interesting, Would you suggest any text where I can find such result and proof @j.q?

Comment: The last result is just the definition of Kronecker product: $H^*(M)$ acts on $H_*(M)$ by $\psi \cdot x = \psi(x)$. What @j.q wrote is just the same thing but with 2 factors on both cohomology and homology.